# How do I place the text to the left of the tabbar?

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Viewer',
      theme:
          ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.cyan, accentColor: Colors.tealAccent),
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //Icon(Icons.settings)
                    Text('Blah'),
                    TabBar(
                      tabs: <Widget>[
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.file_download)),
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(-8),
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.search),
              Icon(Icons.file_download),
              Icon(Icons.settings),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to place the text on the `blah` part visible in the image.
Either way, I want to put a text in the left part of the tabbar.
I tried using row, but an overflow error occurred.
This occurred an error message.
How can I enter the text in that space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code which will work for you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hitomi Viewer',
      theme:
          ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.cyan, accentColor: Colors.tealAccent),
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(-8),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Title'))),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.file_download)),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.search),
              Icon(Icons.file_download),
              Icon(Icons.settings),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OutPut:

[image]

Comment: It's nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by fixing the code as follows:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hitomi Viewer',
      theme:
          ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.cyan, accentColor: Colors.tealAccent),
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Text('Blah'),
                      ),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 80, 0),
                    ),
                    TabBar(
                      tabs: <Widget>[
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.file_download)),
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings))
                      ],
                    ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(-8),
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.search),
              Icon(Icons.file_download),
              Icon(Icons.settings),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for sharing @RollRat. But I can't find the `Text` blah

Comment: Oh my god.. sorry I correct my answer. Please also check the accepted answer written @jitsm555.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `tabs` property is takinig a `List<Widget>`, use the `Text` widget in the `tabs` property instead.

Check the code below:

```
TabBar(
      tabs: <Widget>[
       // put your text widget here
       Text('Blah'),
       Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
       Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.file_download)),
        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings))
       ],
    ),
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is not what I want.
I want to make the `blah` text like Title format. I don't want to use it with one tap.

Comment: This will have problems with the `TabController.length` as they both need to have the same length.

Comment: We are talking about `length` as the number of items, not their size on the scrren. He will have to increase the `TabController` `length` and the `TabBarView` `children` as well. IMHO this can allow for bugs to creep in so I wouldn't suggest this as a solution